# Android First ListView scrolls down to only half of last entry with two ListViews

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have what I thought would be straight forward to implement: A linear layout with two ListViews, both with a layout_weight="1". The first one is "fill parent" and the second one is "wrap content". The idea is that the first ListView is to occupy the entire screen when the second ListView is empty, and when both had entries the screen would be shared. Well, it almost works but when the second ListView is empty, the first ListView scrolls down only half-way through the LAST entry. The remainder of the last entry is off the screen. Does anyone understand why that is the case?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/lni_logo" />

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:choiceMode="none"
  android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:id="@android:id/list" >
</ListView>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:choiceMode="none"
  android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:id="@+id/rtsalist">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Actually at this stage I have not made an adapter for my second ListView so I have not been able to test it with entries in it. But the point is that it should be as if I did not have the ListView at all when it is empty. Alas such is not the case. When I remove the second ListView, the first one scrolls down to the last element correctly, displaying the entire entry.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: **fill_parent** and **match_parent** are the same thing. Use **match_parent** only as **fill_parent** is deprecated.

Comment: You have **layout_weight** set for your **ListView**s, but you need to wrap those two ListViews in a new **LinearLayot** with orientation set to `vertical` and that new LinearLayout needs to have the `android:weightSum` property set to _2_, so they each take up 50%.

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s If one of them is empty will that one occupy any space? What I have done at this point is to pro grammatically set the one that is empty to disappear (rtsaList.setVisibility(View.GONE)). It appears to work but I have not tried it with entries. Of course when I do that I have the second listview's layout_height="match_parent".

Comment: You'll have to programmatically change the layout weight as well to 2. The way you are doing it is just non-standard.

Comment: Okay; that's good to know. Helps me understand layout weights better.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a line like `android:paddingBottom="20dp"` into your top ListView. Adjust the *20dp* value until it looks the way you want it to. You can programmatically change the bottom padding as the list disappears and reappeares to make it look just right.

Comment: I had done that but did not like the results and it doesn't really solve the problem; it only hides it. It also seemed to be different on different phones/tablets. So I decided to go with a ViewFlipper and save precious real estate. In one ListView I will have measurement data and in the other I will have a set of real time graphs. The latter ListView will not have a large number of graphs. But thanks for the help.